# I have an issue with Android Studio after updating it

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated the Android Studio to version 1.4 beta 3 and after updating it gives me an error at the SDK.

I don't know actually what it is, but I tried to change the SDK but it seems nothing changed.

This is the error from Messages Tab:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    E:\Android-DEV\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\build-tools\build-tools-21.1.1\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output E:\AndroidStudioWorkspace\NumbersFinder\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=E:\AndroidStudioWorkspace\NumbersFinder\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error could appear after reaching the default **64K** methods limit.

See here, https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

A simple solution would be adding the **multiDexEnabled** from gradle.

Try to enable **multidex** from **build.gradle** :

```
    android {
       defaultConfig {
          ...
          multiDexEnabled = true
       }
}
```